# Tabular and grid typesetting

Tags: tables, grid-typesetting

In my document, I try to remove most of the vertical stretch, using some of the tricks detailed in [this](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88bazargan.pdf) document. Specifically, I have

```
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-10pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}
```

This, however, does not play nicely with `\cmidrule` from `booktabs`. From other posts, I gleaned, that the `tabular` environment uses different spacing methods, i.e., it sets `\baselineskip` to zero and relies on the `\lineskiplimit` to get correct spacing. This breaks when using the trick above, which is made even more clear when using `\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-999pt}`: any table is rendered as a single line, in which all content is overlapping. What is a good/elegant way to fix this problem?

**edit**: The package `grid` is often mentioned as solving (part of) the grid typesetting issue, but this package also breaks `\tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{grid}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    one & two \\
    three & four \\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If TeX is inserting `\lineskip` you have _already_ been pushed off the grid as the line did not fit within `\baselineskip`, so it isn't clear that disabling this helps in general. If you do disable it then as you say, you need to put it back for tables, and math alignments and several other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using David's suggestion, I used

```
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\oldendtabular\endtabular
\def\tabular{\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{0pt}\oldtabular}
\def\endtabular{\oldendtabular\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-10pt}}
```

which more or less seems to fix the problem. If anyone has a more elegant/better solution, please let me know!

Comment: Hi Michel -- Have you tried using \\ [3pt] at the end of the first row without incorporating David's suggestion.  I did that with your code and I got a non-overlapping text as the David's suggestion would do.

Comment: Jesse, that would mean changing all occurrences of \\ to \\[3pt], in the whole document. I'd rather have it work automatically :)